# Conditional str_replace for pagination

Tags: php, javascript, html, pagination

H everyone,

I have the following:

```
$html = '<ul class="pagination-all">';
    $html .= '<li class="pagination-start"><div class="img-start"></div>'.$list['start']['data'].'</li>';
    $html .= '<li class="pagination-prev"><div class="img-prev"></div>'.$list['previous']['data'].'</li>';
    $html .= '<ul class="pagination-data">';
    foreach($list['pages'] as $page) {
        $html .= '<li>'.$page['data'].'</li>';
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
    $html .= '<li class="pagination-next">'. $list['next']['data'].'<div class="img-next"></div></li>';
    $html .= '<li class="pagination-end">'. $list['end']['data'].'<div class="img-end"></div></li>';
    $html .= '</ul>';

    return $html;
```

I was wondering how to make it so if it finds  Start , string replaces "img-start" to "img-start-active".  If it finds span class="pagenav"> End , string replaces "img-end" to "img-end-active".

I attempted:

```
$string = $html;
if(strstr($string, '<span class="pagenav"> Start </span>'))
{
echo str_replace("img-start", "img-start-active", $string);
}
else
{
echo " ";
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't believe I used this properly. What ended up was - while I got the desired string replacement given the condition, it echoed the whole pagination but without the formatting.

This is the image:[image]

So it was a mess.

Is there a way to do this search and replace but without creating a second "pagination"?

Answer:

```
 $string = $html;
        if(strstr($string, '<span class="pagenav">Start</span>'))
        {
        return str_replace("img-start", "img-start-active", $string);
        }
        else
        {
        echo " ";
        }
```

Remove `return $html;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = $html;
    if(strstr($string, '<span class="pagenav">Start</span>'))
    {
    return str_replace("img-start", "img-start-active", $string);
    }
    else
    {
    echo " ";
    }
```

Remove `return $html;`

Answer (score 1):

What kind of formatting was lost? The original string `$html` has no formatting either :) if you `echo $html;` you will see that there is no formatting there either. If you want, you could add `\n` to the end of each line where you want a newline (make sure to replace the single quotes surrounding the strings with double quotes as well). So for example, your second line would look something like this:

```
$html .= '<li class="pagination-start"><div class="img-start"></div>'.$list['start']['data']."</li>\n";
```

**EDIT** (after question was updated):

In this case, it's probably because the CSS for the new class name is not set. In your css file if you make new classes for `img-start-active` and `img-end-active` with the same contents as `img-start` and `img-end` you shouldn't lose any formatting.

Comment: HI Ansari, thanks for taking the time to look it over. i suppose "formatting" is the incorrect term. It gave me a second set of the original string $html. I was wondering what I'm doing wrong to make it echo twice instead of once like before.

Comment: I don't really understand - it would help if you gave the current output, and the expected output.

Comment: Ah! Thanks - when you said "current output", I realized that I haven't called it correctly!! Thank you so much!